# Sinon fakeserver test times out on promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, mocha.js, sinon

I am just getting into unit testing and currently exploring the Mocha, Chai, Sinon setup, testing this in a browser.

I have a javascript block that makes an ajax call to the server like so

```
PromptBase.prototype.fetchAndSetTemplateString = function() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    url: "/someurl",
    type: "GET"
  })  
  .done(function(response) {
    if (response.status.toLowerCase() === "success") {
      deferred.resolve(response.templateString);
    }   
  });
  return deferred.promise();
};

PromptBase.prototype.fetchPromptTemplate = function() {
  var promise = this.fetchAndSetTemplateString();
  $.when(promise).done(function(promptHtml) {
     //set the templateString to promptHtml here
  });
};
//Register a custom event on document to fire ajax request.
$(document).on("customevent", function(event) {
 promptInstance.fetchPromptTemplate(promptParams.fetchTemplateOnEvent);
});
```

Now I have a test case that looks like this using [fakeServer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer)

```
describe("TemplateFetch", function() {
      before(function() {
        this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); // and other setup
      }); 
      after(function() {
        this.server.restore(); // and other clean up
     }); 

      it("should fetch template string from server, when fetchTemplateEvent is fired", function() {                                                                                                                                           
        var expectedTemplateString = "templateStringFromServer";
        var templateAjaxUrl = '/someurl';
        //faking a server response
        this.server.respondWith("GET", templateAjaxUrl,
          [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
           '{"status": "success", "templateString": "'+ expectedTemplateString +'"}']);

        // Now trigger even that fetches the template
        $(document).trigger("customevent");
        // This calls the ajax done function, which resolves the promise
        this.server.respond(); 

        //debugger shows that templateString is set here
        expect(this.instance.templateString).to.eqaul("something");    
      }); 
    });
```

However my test outputs the timeout error

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

So the `fakeServer.respond()` call ensures that the `ajax->done` function is called resulting in the promise being resolved, And when I debug I can see that the `expect` test should match the two strings. How can I fix the time out issue here? I have also tried adding a done callback but to no avail.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: just to be sure you tried `it('should whatever', function(done) { ... done()}`